# weblogic.jdbc.extensions.PoolDisabledSQLException:

Tags: weblogic

weblogic.jdbc.extensions.PoolDisabledSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDisabledException: Pool XYZ is Suspended, cannot allocate resources to applications.

When My application is heavily loaded(by QA Automations) I get this exceptions.
Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 1):

From the error you provided it looks like Pool is getting suspended. You might want to tune the Datasources configured. When the error is seen again do check Datasource status and try to perform a test.

Also look at complete server logs in which you can see the behavior.